# Compile external HTML which is called by ajax in directive

Tags: angularjs, compilation, directive

How to compile external HTML file ?

I am loading a external HTML file via ajax based on the browser request in directive so is there any way to compile that file so that it can be used in directive?

```
    corpo.directive('corpInbox', function(companyFactory, $templateRequest, $compile) {
      var directive = {};

      directive.restrict = 'A';

      directive.scope = {
        model: '=mgModel'
      }

      directive.link = function($scope, element, attributes) {

        console.log("preparing the inbox........");

        var content = $('.inbox-content', element);
        var loading = $('.inbox-loading', element);
        var listListing = '';

        var loadInbox = function(el, name) {
          var url = 'templates/inbox/inbox_inbox.html';
          var title = $('.inbox-nav > li.' + name + ' a', element).attr('data-title');
          listListing = name;

          loading.show();
          content.html('');
          toggleButton(el);

          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            url: url,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(res) {
              toggleButton(el);

              $('.inbox-nav > li.active', element).removeClass('active');
              $('.inbox-nav > li.' + name, element).addClass('active');
              $('.inbox-header > h1', element).text(title);

              loading.hide();
              content.html(res);
              /*if (Layout.fixContentHeight) {
                        Layout.fixContentHeight();
                    }*/
              //Metronic.initUniform();
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
              toggleButton(el);
            }
          });

          // handle group checkbox:
          jQuery('body').on('change', '.mail-group-checkbox', function() {
            var set = jQuery('.mail-checkbox', element);
            var checked = jQuery(this).is(":checked");
            jQuery(set).each(function() {
              $(this).attr("checked", checked);
            });
            //jQuery.uniform.update(set);
          });
        }
      }
      return directive;
    });
```

Comment: jquery should not be use inside angular code.. you should replace it with `$http`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You should be Using $http instead of $.ajax
And For Compiling you have to inject $compile into your directive. And then use the below code inside the success method of your ajax call to compile the res.

```
var compiledhtml = $compile($(res))($scope);
content.html(compiledhtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Compiling you have to inject $compile into your directive. And then use the below code inside the success method of your ajax call to compile the res.

```
var compiledhtml = $compile($(res))($scope);
content.html(compiledhtml);
```